# Can I expect to be welcome in Pakistan if I'm an Indian?

Tags: indian-citizens, cultural-awareness, history, pakistan

I'm an Indian researching **The Harappan Civilization of India** as my personal interest. Unfortunately after Partition the area is located in Pakistan.

Since India and Pakistan are well-known enemies, can I expect good behaviour from Pakistanis towards me after they realise that my roots are Indian?

Comment: I'm sorry my friend. Anyway thank you for your opinion. I wish to be happen likewise

Comment: [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g297608-d2092263-Reviews-Lothal-Ahmedabad_Gujarat.html) has scores of recent positive reviews by Indian nationals who visited the archaeological site, suggesting that your origins would not be an issue.

Comment: Thats a great information for me @Dorothy. You are almost up to my query. Thankyou friend